# Wicket AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior and performance

Tags: ajax, wicket

I'm using AbstractAjaxWicketBehavior in my Wicket application and it seems to have a descending performance over time when more AJAX calls appear. When a page is refreshed without AJAX, the performance is fine again. I would like to know if this is a normal thing or can be a memory leak of some kind present? I can't simply attach the code as it's spread over more classes and it would require too much effort to understand, but in short I want to do this:

1. create and start the timer
2. repeat some code 10x
3. stop the timer
4. set some values to attributes
5. ajax refresh (causes show/hide of some components)

and do the same again (hypotetically infinite times).

Every repetition of this flow is slower even though I use constant updating interval of 100ms.

As the timer is a behavior and does not allow to be restarted or reused, it is created every time as a new instance and attached to the Form component.

The timer looks like this:

```
static int count = 0
new AbstractAjaxTimerBehavior(Duration.milliseconds(100)) {
 // do some code
 count++
 if(count == 10) {
  stop();
  // do some code
 } 
}
```

This behavior is attached to a Form inside a Panel and upon a click on an AjaxLink the Form is refreshed (added to AjaxRequestTarget). Every time I remove the old timer from the Form component before adding the new behavior.

Everything works fine, but every repetition of this procedure runs slower (The first one is perfect, the second one is also around 100ms, but then it gets slower (after 10 or 15 repetitions, the refresh interval is about 1 second) and all other AJAX calls in the app also go significantly slower), so I suspect there is a memory leak... any obvious reasons? Or any ways how to make a wicket timer better for my purpose? Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Our wicket applications also tend to get slower with every AJAX-Request. I'm not sure if this is the exact same problem or if it relates to the AjaxTimerBehavior in particular, but:

We found that one reason for this are pseudo leaks in the browser that occur due to HTML replacement. Obviously the nrowser cannot free memory until the page is reloaded.

You can monitor Browser Memory with the Task manager (or another Tool) and watch Memory raise with every AJAX-request and how it reliefs on a full page reload (F5). Especially in IE.

We replace alot of HTML with our AJAX-requests though.